# SQL Server 2008: Using SIGN to get positive or negative value

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a large table (millions of recs) containing transaction amounts per transaction type. I'm trying to get the COUNT per each transaction type where the amount is greater than, less than and equal to 0. I was executing 3 separate queries to get this information, changing the WHERE clause in each one and then piecemealing the results together afterwards.

Can someone recommend a more intelligent way to write this statement?

PSEUDO

```
SELECT 
TRANSACTION_CD
,COUNT(TRANSACTION_CD)
FROM [FINANCIAL_TRANSACTION] ft
INNER JOIN POLICY p ON p.POLICY_ID = ft.POLICY_ID
WHERE 
ft.EFFECTIVE_DT > '01/01/2008'
AND SIGN(ft.transaction_amt) = -1
GROUP BY 
TRANSACTION_CD
ORDER BY 
TRANSACTION_CD
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
TRANSACTION_CD
,SUM(CASE WHEN ft.transaction_amt < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NegativeCount
,SUM(CASE WHEN ft.transaction_amt = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ZeroCount
,SUM(CASE WHEN ft.transaction_amt > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PositiveCount
FROM [FINANCIAL_TRANSACTION] ft
INNER JOIN POLICY p ON p.POLICY_ID = ft.POLICY_ID
WHERE 
ft.EFFECTIVE_DT > '01/01/2008'
GROUP BY 
TRANSACTION_CD
ORDER BY 
TRANSACTION_CD
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this recommendation.